# Android - show progress dialog while doing work on UI thread

Tags: android, multithreading, dialog

I need to do some work on the UI thread, specifically setting up some views, etc. - this can't be done in a background thread.  The process is invoked on a button click and takes about a second or so to complete - without a progress dialog it looks as if the app is frozen.  I use progress dialog with `AsynTask`s in several places and it works fine - however here I'm struggling.

I started with simple:

```
showDialog(DIALOG_PLEASE_WAIT);
viewInfo.setFromGuide(true);          //this method just sets a variable
viewInfo.setVenue(venue);             //this method does a lot of UI manipulation and takes a second or so
showScreen(VIEW_INFO);                //this method shows the corresponding view in ViewFlipper
dismissDialog(DIALOG_PLEASE_WAIT);
```

However the dialog would not show (sort of expected, as this is all on UI thread.

Then I changed the code to this:

```
Handler hnd = new Handler() {
    @Override
    handleMessage(Message m) {
        viewInfo.setFromGuide(true);
        viewInfo.setVenue(venue);
        showScreen(VIEW_INFO);
        dismissDialog(DIALOG_PLEASE_WAIT);
    }
}
showDialog(DIALOG_PLEASE_WAIT);
new Thread() {
    public void run() {
       hnd.sendEmptyMessage(0);
    }
}.start();
```

This still doesn't show the dialog - naturally, the UI work in `handleMessage` is still done on the UI thread.  So, what can I do to show the progress dialog?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're doing to make view initialisation take so long, but I suggest showing the user a basic UI while the complex stuff loads. Progress bars for loading UI is a big no-no.

Comment: Majority of the UI initialisation involves setting bitmaps into ImageViews and dynamically creating/adding to the main view custom views diaplaying a set of attributes (from an array of textual name/value pairs).  Unfortunately, it's not as simple to show something and then load the rest.

Comment: Why can't you do these actions on a worker thread and then update the UI with specific methods?

Comment: @Tudor: I'm not sure I follow you.  I have all data prepared already - the UI thread only takes this data and creates UI.  That's why it takes only a second or so.  It takes about 5-7 seconds to prepare the data - and that is done in `AsynTask` in a different place in the app.

Answer (score 0):

If it takes really takes `a second or so to complete` than maybe you can just use a simple Toast notification with a message like "Please wait"

Comment: This may be a solution!  Of course, there's the additional aspect of preventing the user from initiating any other actions on the screen while I'm processing the request.  Dialog would automatically take care of this, but I may be able to use some 'enable/disable' logic instead.

Comment: Tried using a toast - the toast is also not displayed until AFTER all the UI setup is completed and the view is shown - hence it's totally useless.

Answer (score -1):

as you are using `AsyncTask` you can override `onProgressUpdate` which is called when ever you call `publishProgress()` from inside the `doInBackGround` so you can publish your results smoothly while working in background because, `onProgressUpdate` works on the UI thread.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you're referring to.  I don't have any AsyncTasks, all my processing is on the UI thread because it's all about updating the UI.

Comment: actually in your response to @Tudor you said that "is done in AsynTask in a different place in the app" ... anyway you may consider using it... it facilitates a lot of things.

Comment: I was referring to a completely different piece of logic.  AsyncTask loads the data once in the beginning of the app.  Then later in the app (possibly an hour later), I use that data to set up the UI to display it - only if the user invokes the relevant action.